# Trouble getting related entries with grid fields in stash list

Tags: stash, ee3, loop, list, nested-list

I have a channel entry for houses in which the user can enter all the details for a house (I simplified the fields for this). For the home page, I am pulling a list of "model homes" that are a multiple relationship field and stashing them for displaying in my template. So I am inside my channel_entries loop for the home page and down a bit in my stash template. Here is my stash segment for this:

My relationship field in the home page is `Relationship Field = {model_homes}`

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="sv_model_homes" parse_tags="yes"}
    {model_homes}
        {stash:sv_house_url}{model_homes:url_title}{/stash:sv_house_url}
        {stash:sv_overview}{model_homes:overview}{/stash:sv_overview}
        {exp:stash:set_list name="sv_address" parse_tags="yes"}
            {model_homes:address}
                {stash:sv_street}{address:street}{/stash:sv_street}
                {stash:sv_city}{address:city}{/stash:sv_city}
                {stash:sv_state}{address:state}{/stash:sv_state}
                {stash:sv_zip}{address:zip}{/stash:sv_zip}
            {/model_homes:address}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
        {exp:stash:set_list name="sv_house_images" parse_tags="yes"}
            {model_homes:house_images cover_only="yes"}
                {stash:sv_house_image_full}{image:url{/stash:sv_house_image_full}
                {stash:sv_house_image}{image:url:gallery}{/stash:sv_house_image}
                {stash:sv_house_title}{image:title}{/stash:sv_house_title}
            {/model_homes:house_images}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
        {exp:stash:set_list name="sv_details" parse_tags="yes"}
            {model_homes:house_details}
                {stash:sv_price}{house_details:price}{/stash:sv_price}
                {stash:sv_bedrooms}{house_details:bedrooms}{/stash:sv_bedrooms}
                {stash:sv_bathrooms}{house_details:bathrooms}{/stash:sv_bathrooms}
                {stash:sv_living_rooms}{house_details:living_rooms}{/stash:sv_living_rooms}
                {stash:sv_dining_rooms}{house_details:dining_rooms}{/stash:sv_dining_rooms}
                {stash:sv_square_footage}{house_details:square_footage}{/stash:sv_square_footage}
            {/model_homes:house_details}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
    {/model_homes}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Inside the houses channel fields are the following `grid` and `channel_images` fields.

INSIDE the homes entry are the following fields giving me trouble:

```
GRID - {address}

CHANNEL IMAGES - {house_images}

GRID - {house_details}
```

This is my `{content_home}` template (display) for this content segment:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            {exp:stash:get_list name='sv_model_homes'}

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail boxed">
                    <div class="listing-image">
                        <span class="listing-tag important">Model Home</span>
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_house_images'}
                        <img src="{sv_house_image}" alt="{sv_house_title}">
                        <div class="image-links">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a class="inner" href="{sv_house_image_full}" data-lightbox="related-1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <a class="inner" href="{site_url}house/{sv_house_url}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_details'}
                        <div class="image-tags">
                            <ul class="property-tags">
                                <li><span><i class="icon-bed"></i> {sv_bedrooms}<br><span class="small">Bedrooms</span></span></li>
                                <li><span><i class="icon-shower"></i> {sv_bathrooms}<br><span class="small">Bathrooms</span></span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_address'}
                        <h4>{sv_street}<br><small>{sv_city}, {sv_state}</small></h4>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_details'}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <strong>Property Size:</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                {sv_square_footage} SqFt
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <strong>Rooms:</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                {sv_bedrooms} Bed, {sv_bathrooms} Bath
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                                                    <span class="price-tag">
                                                        ${sv_price}
                                                    </span>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        <a href="{site_url}house/{sv_house_url}" class="btn btn-link " role="button">+ Show Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/exp:stash:get_list}

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I AM getting information, just not the correct information.

If I test the loop like this:

```
<div class="row">
    {exp:stash:get_list name='sv_model_homes'}
        {sv_house_url} - {count}<br>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
</div>
```

I get the proper `{sv_house_url}` and `{count}`. It loops through the trhee tests and count 1, 2, 3.

However, in my markup for `{content_home}`, (above), I just get the first entry. I've tried using the `prefix=''`tag, but that didn't change anything for me. (I could have been using it incorrectly too though.)

What do I need to do in order to get the proper data from my stash set_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks for the input @Natetronn. If this is what you were talking about, let me know so I can accept your answer. :)

I tried using the context param before and after rounding out the nesting, but wasn't able to get it functioning properly for this. Even after nesting the lists I was still just capturing a single one of the loop data sets. I think the context parameter is supposed to handle setting and retrieving this way too from what I read, but I wasn't able to get that working. If I am doing this the hard way and context works this way, please let me know so that I can utilize the addon properly.  :)

I was able to achieve my desired results using the following "set_list". Again, simplified, but I'm including the `{channels_entry}` tags to make it more clear for those that may need more info.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="home_page"
    limit="1"
}
    {exp:stash:sv_title}{title}{/exp:stash:sv_title}
    {exp:stash:sv_url_title}{url_title}{/exp:stash:sv_url_title}
    {exp:stash:sv_entry_id}{entry_id}{/exp:stash:sv_entry_id}
    {exp:stash:sv_entry_date}{entry_date format="%Y %m %d"}{/exp:stash:sv_entry_date}
    {exp:stash:sv_edit_date}{edit_date format="%Y %m %d"}{/exp:stash:sv_edit_date}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="slideshow_images" parse_tags="yes"}
        {slideshow}
            {slideshow:slider_images}
                {stash:sv_slideshow_image}{image:url:slider-optimized}{/stash:sv_slideshow_image}
                {stash:sv_slideshow_title}{image:title}{/stash:sv_slideshow_title}
            {/slideshow:slider_images}
        {/slideshow}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
    {exp:stash:sv_welcome_title}{welcome_title}{/exp:stash:sv_welcome_title}
    {exp:stash:sv_welcome_greeting}{welcome_greeting}{/exp:stash:sv_welcome_greeting}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="sv_model_homes" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
        {model_homes}
            {stash:sv_house_id}{model_homes:entry_id}{/stash:sv_house_id}
            {stash:sv_house_url}{model_homes:url_title}{/stash:sv_house_url}
            {stash:sv_overview}{model_homes:overview}{/stash:sv_overview}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="sv_address_{model_homes:entry_id}" context parse_tags="yes"}
                {model_homes:address}
                    {stash:sv_street}{address:street}{/stash:sv_street}
                    {stash:sv_city}{address:city}{/stash:sv_city}
                    {stash:sv_state}{address:state}{/stash:sv_state}
                    {stash:sv_zip}{address:zip}{/stash:sv_zip}
                {/model_homes:address}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="sv_house_images_{model_homes:entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {model_homes:house_images cover_only="yes"}
                    {stash:sv_house_image_full}{image:url}{/stash:sv_house_image_full}
                    {stash:sv_house_image}{image:url:gallery}{/stash:sv_house_image}
                    {stash:sv_house_title}{image:title}{/stash:sv_house_title}
                {/model_homes:house_images}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="sv_details_{model_homes:entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {model_homes:house_details}
                    {stash:sv_price}{house_details:price}{/stash:sv_price}
                    {stash:sv_bedrooms}{house_details:bedrooms}{/stash:sv_bedrooms}
                    {stash:sv_bathrooms}{house_details:bathrooms}{/stash:sv_bathrooms}
                    {stash:sv_living_rooms}{house_details:living_rooms}{/stash:sv_living_rooms}
                    {stash:sv_dining_rooms}{house_details:dining_rooms}{/stash:sv_dining_rooms}
                    {stash:sv_square_footage}{house_details:square_footage}{/stash:sv_square_footage}
                {/model_homes:house_details}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
        {/model_homes}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in my "get_list", I achieved what I needed by pulling out the data like this:

```
<div class="flexslider title-slider" data-animation="fade" data-loop="true">
    <div class="title">Model Homes</div>
    <ul class="slides">
        {exp:stash:get_list name='sv_model_homes'}
            {switch='<li><div class="row">||'}
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail boxed">
                    <div class="listing-image">
                        <span class="listing-tag important">Model Home</span>
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_house_images_{sv_house_id}'}
                            <img src="{sv_house_image}" alt="{sv_house_title}">
                            <div class="image-links">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <a class="inner" href="{sv_house_image_full}" data-lightbox="related-1">
                                        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <a class="inner" href="{site_url}house/{sv_house_url}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_details_{sv_house_id}'}
                            <div class="image-tags">
                                <ul class="property-tags">
                                    <li><span><i class="icon-bed"></i> {sv_bedrooms}<br><span class="small">Bedrooms</span></span></li>
                                    <li><span><i class="icon-shower"></i> {sv_bathrooms}<br><span class="small">Bathrooms</span></span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_address_{sv_house_id}'}
                            <h4>{sv_street}<br><small>{sv_city}, {sv_state}</small></h4>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='sv_details_{sv_house_id}'}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <strong>Property Size:</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    {sv_square_footage} SqFt
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <strong>Rooms:</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    {sv_bedrooms} Bed, {sv_bathrooms} Bath
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <span class="price-tag">
                                ${sv_price}
                            </span>
                        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                        <a href="{site_url}house/{sv_house_url}" class="btn btn-link " role="button">+ Show Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {if count == absolute_results}
                </div></li>
            {if:else}
                {switch='||</div></li>'}
            {/if}
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgot to nest your nested set_lists? Looks like you're doing it on your nested get_lists, however.

These set_lists need to be nested.

- sv_address
- sv_house_images
- sv_details

Also, I'm not sure but, you may need to use the [context param](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset%7D#context---string-) on those nested set_lists and nested get_lists too. Maybe along with the `{entry_id}`. And this would come after fixing your nesting so if nesting fixes all your issues then disregard this part.